# Plugin framework,parameter passing,c++,dll,gdi+

Tags: c++, windows, plugins, dll, gdi+

I am creating a plugin framework as mentioned in tutorial [enter link description here](http://www.andynicholas.com/?p=27)

Here PluginInterface class looks like

```
class PluginInterface
{
   public:
      PluginInterface(){}
      virtual ~PluginInterface(){}

      virtual int Activate()=0;
      virtual int Execute()=0;
      virtual int Destroy()=0;
};
```

Instead I want my plugin class to be like below:

```
class PluginInterface
{
   public:
      PluginInterface(){}
      virtual ~PluginInterface(){}

      virtual int Process(Image *)=0;

};
```

Is is possible that I can pass Image* from my application to plugin and plugin can do some processing on it??

Image is gdiplus object . My thinking is that plugin dll will be loaded in same memory space as that of applicaiton , so if my application allocates memory for Image object so that should be available for plugin also and plugin can perform operations on that Image.

If this is possible , then do I need to statically link plugin with gdiplus.lib using

```
#pragma comment(lib, "gdiplus.lib")
```

Since my applcation is already statically linked with gdiplus,I am not sure if that is again required for plugin.

Answer (score 0):

This will be required if you gonna call any gdiplus.dll functions from your plugin and compile plugin separately from its host application.

And to be honest this is called implicit dynamic linking, not static.